# Does the common matrix expression $A \cdot B \cdot A'$ have a name?

Tags: matrices, transpose

In an algorithm I'm working with, the same type of expression comes up multiple times:

$X = A \cdot B \cdot A'$

Where $A$ is a row-vector, $B$ is a square matrix, and then (naturally) $A'$ is a column vector, so the result $X$ is a scalar value.

Since this comes up so often, I thought the expression might have a name.
But it has been difficult to google for this, and I have no idea what it might be called.

Is there a common name for this operation to take a vector and matrix to produce a scalar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This construction define a map $V\to\mathbb R$, where $V$ is a vector space
of dimension $n$ and $B$ is a $n\times n$ matrix. That is, vectors $A$ in $V$ are transformed to the scalar is a map
$$A\mapsto ABA^{\top},$$
that is dubbed quadratic form.

Comment: quadratic forms can be solved for the decision variable $A$ with **quadratic programming**, a type of convex optimization

Comment: @develarist... do you know if $A\mapsto ABA^{\top}$ is surjective?